# How do I deploy an already developed ASP.NET MVC application to Azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I created a free trial account with Azure and also have a fully developed ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3 project with several other projects in the same solution that either provide services to or depend on the ASP.NET MVC project.

When creating the project in Visual Studio, I did not select the **Host in the cloud** checkbox.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. I now want to create an app service in Azure and deploy this application there.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

When right clicking on your project, you get a "**Publish**" option:

[image: Project Publish]

Once selected, you will get the option to select and deploy to an **Azure App Service**:

[image: Azure Publish choice]

Continue then on next screen to create an existing Azure App Service to deploy to, or create a new one in yoru linked Azure Subscription.

Comment: That's "one" way (there are also vm's. Also, there are many other things to deal with (db connections, caching, session state, etc),

Comment: Question is stating "I now want to create an app service in Azure". I am assuming that connection handling and other mentioned elements are handled, as the question is not pointing to those.

Comment: Didn't see that part. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, @bsoulier, I am tryinig out what you said. I know that I'll have to change the connection string and set up a key vault to store my secrets in there. I'll do that once I have this app published to AppService. It is taking a hell of a long time.